# Installing Ubuntu on an old PC running Windows 8 Consumer Preview

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have an old PC running Windows 8 Consumer Preview. The PC initially had Windows Vista.

I downloaded the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and made a bootable pendrive. In the Ubuntu installation options, I clicked the install into a hard drive but after a while it shows me a black screen with a cursor and I can't get any further.

What should I do? Should I try the 64 bit version?

Comment: System make and Model?

Comment: Largely speaking if it supports Vista and W8, it's going to support Ubuntu. I wouldn't expect 64bit to be any *more* compatible. As Mitch suggests, edit your question to give as much technical information about the hardware as you can.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common problem with the "make bootdisk" program. Try "unetbootin" and let us know if this worked.